# Change confirm-box default positions

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, desktop

I would like to change default position of confirm boxes.

For example:

When I clicking on Shutdown button, the confirm box position is located on `Top-Left` by default.

How do I change default position ?

**Shot :**

I'm Using Arch + XFCE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in XFCE it's not possible to let windows remember their position.
In your menu **Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Placement** or just type the `xfwm4-tweaks-settings` command and choose the option you prefer : Put window in screen center or at the mouse cursor.

Anytime you get a window in an uncomfortable place you can move it anywhere by dragging it with the mouse (use left button) while holding the **Alt** key.

By the way, you can also try the command line tool `wmctrl` witch allow you switch workspaces, move windows between workspaces, move windows positions, maximize windows, etc..

Comment: I would provide you some screen-shots to explain more but by system language is in French so it wouldn't be suitable to illustrate your case !